# Can't manage display for article

Tags: nodes, display-suite, entities

I have done something and can no longer edit the manage display pages for the article content type .  When I try to visit them I fall out of the usual rich html interface into a page whose code is attached below.  I think that this is happening because I have accidentally damaged or removed the full content view mode for the article, but I am a newbie so I am really not sure.  I was playing with Display Suite when this problem began.

Any ideas what is going on? and how to fix it?  Thanks.

```
  <div id="branding" class="clearfix">
    <h2 class="element-invisible">You are here</h2><div class="breadcrumb"><a href="/drupal7/">Home</a> » <a href="/drupal7/?q=admin">Administration</a> » <a href="/drupal7/?q=admin/structure" title="Administer blocks, content types, menus, etc.">Structure</a> » <a href="/drupal7/?q=admin/structure/types" title="Manage content types, including default status, front page promotion, comment settings, etc.">Content types</a> » <a href="/drupal7/?q=admin/structure/types/manage/article">Article</a></div>              <h1 class="page-title">Article</h1>
        <div class="add-or-remove-shortcuts add-shortcut"><a href="/drupal7/?q=admin/config/user-interface/shortcut/shortcut-set-1/add-link-inline&amp;link=admin/structure/types/manage/article/display&amp;name=Article&amp;destination=admin/structure/types/manage/article/display&amp;token=sfNEjW3fhzg0KSwbxJKEEx_mwmWcqqCQjgxWGn5Q27A"><span class="icon"></span><span class="text">Add to <em class="placeholder">Default</em> shortcuts</span></a></div>    <h2 class="element-invisible">Primary tabs</h2><ul class="tabs primary"><li><a href="/drupal7/?q=admin/structure/types/manage/article">Edit</a></li>
<li><a href="/drupal7/?q=admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields">Manage fields</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="/drupal7/?q=admin/structure/types/manage/article/display" class="active">Manage display<span class="element-invisible">(active tab)</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/drupal7/?q=admin/structure/types/manage/article/comment/fields">Comment fields</a></li>
<li><a href="/drupal7/?q=admin/structure/types/manage/article/comment/display">Comment display</a></li>
</ul>  </div>

  <div id="page">
          <div class="tabs-secondary clearfix"><ul class="tabs secondary"><h2 class="element-invisible">Secondary tabs</h2><ul class="tabs secondary"><li class="active"><a href="/drupal7/?q=admin/structure/types/manage/article/display" class="active">Default<span class="element-invisible">(active tab)</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/drupal7/?q=admin/structure/types/manage/article/display/teaser">Teaser</a></li>
</ul></ul></div>

    <div id="content" class="clearfix">
      <div class="element-invisible"><a id="main-content"></a></div>
                    <div id="help">
            <div class="region region-help">
    <div id="block-system-help" class="block block-system">


  <div class="content">
    <p>Content items can be displayed using different view modes: Teaser, Full content, Print, RSS, etc. <em>Teaser</em> is a short format that is typically used in lists of multiple content items. <em>Full content</em> is typically used when the content is displayed on its own page.</p><p>Here, you can define which fields are shown and hidden when <em class="placeholder">Article</em> content is displayed in each view mode, and define how the fields are displayed in each view mode.</p>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling/uninstalling the DS module?

Comment: I uninstalled DS but now I get Error

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.  With a message too long to include here.  Think it's time to reinstall drupal.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable text format as Full Html.

In your html code there were two closing div are missed. here is the closing div added.

```
<div class="clearfix" id="branding">
    <h2 class="element-invisible">You are here</h2>

    <div class="breadcrumb"><a href="/drupal7/">Home</a> » <a href="/drupal7/?q=admin">Administration</a> » <a href="/drupal7/?q=admin/structure" title="Administer blocks, content types, menus, etc.">Structure</a> » <a href="/drupal7/?q=admin/structure/types" title="Manage content types, including default status, front page promotion, comment settings, etc.">Content types</a> » <a href="/drupal7/?q=admin/structure/types/manage/article">Article</a></div>

    <h1 class="page-title">Article</h1>

    <div class="add-or-remove-shortcuts add-shortcut"><a href="/drupal7/?q=admin/config/user-interface/shortcut/shortcut-set-1/add-link-inline&amp;link=admin/structure/types/manage/article/display&amp;name=Article&amp;destination=admin/structure/types/manage/article/display&amp;token=sfNEjW3fhzg0KSwbxJKEEx_mwmWcqqCQjgxWGn5Q27A"><span class="text">Add to <em class="placeholder">Default</em> shortcuts</span></a></div>

    <h2 class="element-invisible">Primary tabs</h2>

    <ul class="tabs primary">
        <li><a href="/drupal7/?q=admin/structure/types/manage/article">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="/drupal7/?q=admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields">Manage fields</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a class="active" href="/drupal7/?q=admin/structure/types/manage/article/display">Manage display<span class="element-invisible">(active tab)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="/drupal7/?q=admin/structure/types/manage/article/comment/fields">Comment fields</a></li>
        <li><a href="/drupal7/?q=admin/structure/types/manage/article/comment/display">Comment display</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="page">
    <div class="tabs-secondary clearfix">
        <h2 class="element-invisible">Secondary tabs</h2>

        <ul class="tabs secondary">
            <li>
                <ul class="tabs secondary">
                    <li class="active"><a class="active" href="/drupal7/?q=admin/structure/types/manage/article/display">Default<span class="element-invisible">(active tab)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/drupal7/?q=admin/structure/types/manage/article/display/teaser">Teaser</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix" id="content">
        <div class="element-invisible">&nbsp;</div>

        <div id="help">
            <div class="region region-help">
                <div class="block block-system" id="block-system-help">
                    <div class="content">
                        <p>Content items can be displayed using different view modes: Teaser, Full content, Print, RSS, etc. <em>Teaser</em> is a short format that is typically used in lists of multiple content items. <em>Full content</em> is typically used when the content is displayed on its own page.</p>

                        <p>Here, you can define which fields are shown and hidden when <em class="placeholder">Article</em> content is displayed in each view mode, and define how the fields are displayed in each view mode.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```